# How to identify user in AWS IoT when using AWS Cognito for authentication and authorization?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-iot

Im trying to user AWS IoT and AWS Cognito in combination. Basically using AWS Cognito for authentication and authorization. So how can I identify at the server side which user has published the event?

Comment: What are you using at server side? Is it lambda function?

Comment: Yup @AarthTandel

Comment: Is it a MQTT based Pub/Sub also, Are all users Authenticated ?

Comment: Yeah users are authenticated, but how to which user is sending the message

Comment: In the case of MQTT you get the details when the user connects to the thing. But it has to be handled manually there is no automatic provision to do so.

Comment: When using certificate-based auth we can get principalId(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-principal) but with Cognito, I'm unable to figure out anything. Thanks for the reply